Fast computation of 2D-convolution using "kernel" in fourier space
I want to numerically evaluate the following integral:

If the function f is given in discrete form on a grid, I want to be able to very efficiently compute the integral. The idea is to understand it as a multiplication in the Fourier space and use FFT:

if xi and eta are the Fourier variables. I tried to implement this in Matlab, but dont get exact results (probably because I dont quite understand the FFT).
I have the following minimal working example in Matlab:
N = 101;
x = linspace(-1, 1, N); hx = x(2)-x(1);
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x, x);

a = 1/2;
f = 2/pi*a*real(sqrt(1-(X.^2+Y.^2)/a^2));
f_pad = zeros(2*N, 2*N); f_pad(1:N, 1:N) = f;

k = linspace(0, pi/hx, N+1); k = [k k(end-1:-1:2)]; hk = k(3)-k(2);
[KX, KY] = meshgrid(k, k);
K = sqrt(KX.^2 + KY.^2);

chess = mod((1:2*N)+(1:2*N)',2); chess = -chess; chess(chess==0) = 1;

G = 1./K;
G(1,1) = 4*integral2(@(x,y) 1./(sqrt(x.^2+y.^2)),0,0.5*hk,0,0.5*hk)/hk^2;

R = ifft2(G.*2.*chess.*fft2(f_pad), 'symmetric'); 
R = R(N+1:end, N+1:end);

Rana = (a^2-x.^2/2) .* (abs(x)<=a) + ...
       real(a^2/pi*((2-x.^2/a^2).*asin(a./abs(x))+sqrt(x.^2-a^2)/a)) .* (abs(x)>a);

plot(Rana);
hold on;
plot(R((N-1)/2+1,:));

R is the result of the integral, f is the input function and G is the fraction in the Fourier-space; the singularity at xi = 0 and eta = 0 of G is dealt with by taking the average value of the function in the surroundings of the point.
I compare the final result to an analytical solution, which in this case exists. But it doesn't match perfectly (and doesn't get better, when I increase N? Why is that? And I also don't understand why the chess-matrix is necessary (I copied it from an example I found)?

I can't advise on the Matlab but I would hazard a guess that the chess matrix is to shift the phase centre after the convolution. Otherwise the output of the convolution will be centred on the natural phase centre of the FFT at (0,0). I suspect that your problem with accuracy is because 1/sqrt(eta^2+nu^2) only decreases slowly so that truncation errors are significant when you have a very finite grid. Try it with exp(-x^2) or without the sqrt() and I would expect much better agreement with theory.

The second factor inside the curly braces is missing a Fourier transform, isn't it?

Note that the FFT computes a discrete Fourier transform, not a continuous-domain Fourier transform. They are not the same thing, even though the former can be used to approximate the latter. The DFT is periodic, both in the input and the output. You need to take this into account. You also need to take sampling theory into account.

N = 101;
x = linspace(-1, 1, N); hx = x(2)-x(1);
y = linspace(-1, 1, N); hy = y(2)-y(1);
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x, x);

a = 1/2;
F1 = 2/pi*a*real(sqrt(1-(X.^2+Y.^2)/a^2));   % f(x,y)

this is f(x,y) with a=.5
figure(1)
hs=surf(X,Y,F1)
hs.EdgeColor='none';


And f1 is the integrant, the actual function to integrate 2D
f1 = @(x_,y_) 2/pi*a*real(sqrt(1-(x_.^2+y_.^2)/a^2))

Setting x=.5;y=.5; as parameters.
x0=.5;y0=.5;
F2=@(x1,y1) f1(x1,y1)./((x0-x1).^2+(y0-y1).^2).^.5;  

Z=integral2(F2,x(1),x(end),y(1),y(end));

resulting in
Warning: Reached the maximum number of function evaluations
(10000). The result fails the global error test. 
> In integral2Calc>integral2t (line 129)
In integral2Calc (line 9)
In integral2 (line 105)
In double_integral_example (line 23) 
Warning: Reached the limit on the maximum number of intervals
in use. Approximate bound on error is   1.6e-15. The integral
may not exist, or it may be difficult to approximate
numerically to the requested accuracy. 
> In integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 372)
In integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
In integralCalc (line 75)
In integral2Calc>@(xi,y1i,y2i)integralCalc(@(y)fun(xi*ones(size(y)),y),y1i,y2i,opstruct.integralOptions) (line 17)
In integral2Calc>@(x)arrayfun(@(xi,y1i,y2i)integralCalc(@(y)fun(xi*ones(size(y)),y),y1i,y2i,opstruct.integralOptions),x,ymin(x),ymax(x)) (line 17)
In integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 323)
In integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
In integralCalc (line 75)
In integral2Calc>integral2i (line 20)
In integral2Calc (line 7)
In integral2 (line 105)
In double_integral_example (line 26) 
Warning: The integration was unsuccessful. 
> In integral2 (line 108)
In double_integral_example (line 26) 

function integral2 needs some fields changed from default to return a result
Z=integral2(F2,x(1),x(end),y(1),y(end),'Method','iterated','AbsTol',0,'RelTol',1e-10)

Z =
   NaN

too strict
Z=integral2(F2,x(1),x(end),y(1),y(end),'Method','iterated','AbsTol',1e-5,'RelTol',1e-8)
    
    Z =
       0.250008992645364

Now it works
I am submitting the above lines as answer while one of my machines is busy calculating the following
F3=zeros(N,N);

for k1=1:1:numel(x)
    for k2=1:1:numel(y)
        
        x0=x(k1);y0=y(k2);
        F2=@(x1,y1) f1(x1,y1)./((x0-x1).^2+(y0-y1).^2).^.5; 
        
        F3(k1,k2)=integral2(F2,x(1),x(end),y(1),y(end),'Method','iterated','AbsTol',1e-5,'RelTol',1e-8);
        
    end
end

figure(2)
hs3=surf(X,Y,F3)


The narrow gap is again MATLAB getting results but error out of specs.

Comment:
Double loop on integral2 is not time efficient for N>10 , at least for the machine I used to answer this question.
There are other ways to get a result for large N but since
understand that would be another question, on how to optimize an already working solution to the above question.
